# Drawing colored circles using Ruby and Tk

Tags: beginner, ruby, graphics, tk

I am a high-school freshman who is kinda new to Ruby, and I am doing a small project on Ruby.  One of the big things that I want to get out of this project is how to follow the "Ruby standards" that programmers should follow.  Being as new as I am, I have no clue what I should/shouldn't do with this program.  Can anybody tell me what I could do to improve it to fit the community's standards?

```
require 'tk'

$point_A = [0,0]
$point_B = [750,750]
$rate = 1.5
$i=0
circs=Array.new

def before_drawing()
    $point_A = []
    temp_a = $point_B[0]**1/$rate
    temp_b = $point_B[1]**1/$rate
    $point_A << temp_a
    $point_A << temp_b
end

def after_drawing()
   $point_B = []
   $point_B = $point_A
end

canvas = TkCanvas.new(:width=>800, :height=>800).pack('fill' => 'both', 'expand'=>true)

while $i<10 do
    before_drawing()
    circs[$i] = TkcOval.new(canvas, $point_A, $point_B)
    if $i%2==0 then
        circs[$i][:fill] = 'blue'
    else
        circs[$i][:fill] = 'red'
    end
    after_drawing()
    $i+=1
end

Tk.mainloop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define arrays with `[]` not `Array.new`

`circs` should be `$circs` in case you wrap your loop in some function.

Before drawing can be turned into this :

```
def before_drawing()
    temp_a = $point_B[0] ** 1 / $rate
    temp_b = $point_B[1] ** 1 / $rate
    $point_A = [temp_a, temp_b]
end
```

You should turn `$i` into a local variable for the loop. There is no need for it to be global.

Then replace the loop with `upto`.

```
0.upto(10) do |i|
    before_drawing()

    circs[i] = TkcOval.new(canvas, $point_A, $point_B)
    # As suggested using ternary operator
    # circs [i] [:fill] = i % 2 == 0 ? 'blue' : 'red'

    if i % 2 == 0 then
        circs[i][:fill] = 'blue'
    else
        circs[i][:fill] = 'red'
    end

    after_drawing()
end
```

You seem to use too many global variables. My advice would be to prefer local variables whenever you can (Like i in the loop). All your global variables can also be made local to the loop (or function in case you wrap the loop in some function).

Comment: Alrighty, that makes sense..  I had no idea that something like `upto` existed, and I was afraid to use `x.times{}`

Comment: I would recommend to change `if i % 2 == 0 then circs[i][:fill] = 'blue' else circs[i][:fill] = 'red' end` to `circs[i][:fill] = (i % 2 == 0 ? 'blue' : 'red')` or even `circs[i][:fill] = %w{blue red}[i % 2]`.

Comment: Using the ternary operator isn't a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Some notes:

1. Use tabspace=2.
2. Don't use global variables. When programming you should use functions in the same sense than you do in maths. That's a real function: `f(x, y) = x + y`, note that it takes arguments and returns some output (no globals, no states, no updates to variables outside the function).
3. Ruby is a OOP language, so we usually define a class (or module) to contain our code.
4. Don't overuse statements, use expressions. This code uses statements: `x = []; x << 1; x << 2`, this one uses expressions: `x = [1, 2]`.
5. You are writing a loop where the output is the input of the next iteration. That can be written with `Enumerable#inject` (this method is somewhat difficult to grasp at first, study the docs carefully).

A more idiomatic Ruby approach would be:

```
require 'tk'

class Example
  def initialize(options = {}) 
    @rate = options[:rate] || 1.5
    @start_point = options[:start_point] || [750, 750]
    @canvas_size = options[:canvas_size] || [800, 800]
  end

  def run
    canvas = TkCanvas.new(:width => @canvas_size[0], :height => @canvas_size[1])
    canvas.pack('fill' => 'both', 'expand' => true)

    1.upto(10).inject(@start_point) do |point, index|
      # get_next_point is a one-liner and could be written here,
      # but let's show how to use arguments to call functions/methods.
      point2 = get_next_point(point, @rate)
      circle = TkcOval.new(canvas, point, point2)
      circle[:fill] = (index % 2) == 0 ? "red" : "blue"
      point2
    end
    Tk.mainloop
  end

  def get_next_point(point, rate)
    [point[0] / rate, point[1] / rate]
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  example = Example.new(:rate => 1.5, :start_point => [750, 750])
  example.run
end
```

Comment: Ruby may be OOP, but it's also a scripting language designed for building small purpose-built scripts. There is no need to shoe-horn in a class definition for such a small program, but if this is meant to be the foundation of a larger app then it's definitely a good idea.

Comment: @meagar, I agree, but as you say I tried to show good practices for medium/large scripts.

Answer (score 2):

This is slightly late, but I feel like the existing answers are somewhat over-wrought.

A few points:

- `10.times`, as others have mentioned
- You're not using `**` correctly: `x ** 1 / rate` is the same as `(x ** 1) / rate`, and `x ** 1` equals `x`. So, things are cleaned up right away by replacing `** 1 / rate` with `/ rate`
- You can pass `:fill` directly to the constructor of `TkcOval`, meaning you don't need to store your circles at all
- If you *do* need to store the circles, you can use `circles = (0..9).map { |i| ...}` instead of `10.times` and return the circle from the block
- You can compute color on one line using the ternary operator, or, better yet, store the colors in an array (`colors = %w(blue red)`) which can ban indexed by `i % 2`
- Because we're dealing with maths, I prefer to store the points outside an array as `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`. I think this makes things clearer than using arrays. Clearer still would be using points with `.x` and `.y` members like `p1.x, p1.y`, but that isn't supported
- There is no need for your before/after methods, because they're doing next to nothing. They should be written as single lines of code.

Here's the results, about 10 lines of extremely concise and idiomatic code:

```
require 'tk'

canvas = TkCanvas.new(:width => 800, :height => 800).pack('fill' => 'both', 'expand' => true)

x1, y1, rate = 750, 750, 1.5

colors = %w(blue red)

10.times do |i|
  x2, y2 = x1 / rate, y1 / rate
  TkcOval.new(canvas, [x1, y1], [x2, y2], :fill => colors[i % 2])
  x1, y1 = x2, y2
end

Tk.mainloop
```

Note that we could get even shorter and ditch x2/y2, but I feel this starts to verge on code-golf rather than simply writing concise code:

```
require 'tk'

canvas = TkCanvas.new(:width => 800, :height => 800).pack('fill' => 'both', 'expand' => true)

x, y, colors, rate = 750, 750, %w(blue red), 1.5

10.times do |i|
  TkcOval.new(canvas, [x, y], [x /= rate, y /= rate], :fill => colors[i % 2])
end

Tk.mainloop
```

Furthermore, note some style issues:

- *two spaces* for indentation, no more no less
- *don't prefix your variables with `$`*, you're making global variables needlessly.